# CSS: How would I make all the columns' height one line and remove the redundant spaces?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about making the other divs' height the same as the first three rows? There should be no reason it appends to the next line as it's the same length as the other strings. I don't want to set the height using pixels. I'd also like to know how to center my content into the divs both vertically and horizontally.

Thank you.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/htcpfruv/

```
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background-color: #eee;
background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are describing. They are all the same height.

Comment: @Andrew Widen the preview window.

Comment: `.col-md-2` change to `.col-md-3` it will not break but only 4 will come on one line

Comment: @NGLN Hmm... I widened, narrowed it; still all the same height. Maybe it's browser-specific? (I'm on Chrome/Win)

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I was going to post images, but I am only limited to 2 links. I thought JsFiddle would suffice.

Comment: A screen shot might be useful.

Comment: you want this http://jsfiddle.net/bfhyhygy/

Comment: Thanks you, guys. It seems as if Vitorino's answer fixed the sizing issue.

Comment: Here is the screenshot you requested, Andew. http://i.imgur.com/9ZqNhp1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - [**Full-screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/htcpfruv/1/embedded/result/)

changed form `col-md-2` to `col-md-3` will adjust the text

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 columnFixedHeight"><span class="boldSpan">0. </span>0A3PJ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, stop them wrapping by using `white-space:nowrap;` and centre them using `text-align:center`:

```
.columnFixedHeight {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
    white-space:nowrap;/* <- added this to stop wrapping */
    text-align:center;/* <- and this to center the text *
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htcpfruv/3/